# Field To Display Message

Tags: 7, entities

Is there any Field to display Message and Images instead of taking values ??

In Drupal Commerce I have created few fields to take Custom Measurements on Order Settings page.

Now I need to display a Picture and a text message on the page where I am taking measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Markup](https://drupal.org/project/markup) module using which you can add text or HTML which will display a picture..

Project page says

> This module adds the ability for site admins to add "Markup" widgets
>   to the form. These essentially let designers of cck content-types
>   insert additional markup into the node/edit form to display to
>   content-authors. This is the equivalent of adding additional elements
>   to $form of the type '#markup'.